# NSTextAlignmentCenter for UILabel not working

Tags: ios, uilabel, xib, text-alignment

I have a view with a `UILabel` in a separated `nib` file. I load this `nib` file within the `viewWillAppear:` method of an `UIViewController`, and I'm trying to set the `textAlignment` property of the `UILabel` there, this way:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
            {
                self.customView = (MyView *)view;

                ((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

                ((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel.text = @"My text";
                [((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel sizeToFit];

                [self.view addSubview:self.customView];
            }
        }
}
```

But when I run the app, the text is not centered, even if I set the alignment in the `nib` (I can see the text centered in Xcode's IB). This is an app for iOS 7+ and I'm using Xcode 6.1.1. Why could this be not working?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be, it works great.

Comment: if u call `sizeToFit` method, then the size of the `Label` frame will change to `text` size. so it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is coming from :

```
[((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Centering does not change the `frame.origin.x` of your label.
But if you apply `sizeToFit` afterwards, all content will be centered in a smaller zone (without changing the x offset) and will get the feeling that it's not centered anymore.

Comment: I recalculate the X for the label after fitting its size, because I need to fit the label's height... now it is correctly displayed, thanks. Thanks to @LlamaGoingNorth as well

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `[((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel sizeToFit];` and from the docs `sizeToFit` "Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.".

You shouldn't be able to center text in a `UILabel` if the text fills the label.

Try to remove this method call and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

For UILabels with NSTextAlignmentCenter, you can center the label afterwards like this:

```
float w = self.view.frame.size.width;

title.text = @"What do you want to say?";

[title sizeToFit];

title.frame = CGRectMake((w-title.frame.size.width)/2, title.frame.origin.y, title.frame.size.width, title.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel sizeToFit];
```

remove this line...

Comment: [((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel sizeToFit]; remove this line only

Answer (score 0):

Write this line of code

```
((MyView *)self.customView).myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

after this one

```
[self.view addSubview:self.customView];
```